# WPF Converter to look up in generic list

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a list of data where I keep e.g. countries with code, name and some other data.

```
List<Country> countries = <deserialized objects from file>
```

which consist of objects like this:

```
  public class Country
  {
       public string Code { get; set;}
       public string Name { get; set;}
  }
```

The object which use as a DataContext may look like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public string StreetName{ get; set;}
    public string CountryCode { get; set;}
}
```

Then in my XAML I want to do something like this to show the name of the country

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryCode, Converter={StaticResource CountryNameLookupConverter}}"/>
```

But how can I make the CountryNameLookupConverter use the countries list I read from the xml file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on where you're exposing the countries collection there are a few different options.

If countries exists in Address or some other ViewModel object you change your converter to implement IMultiValueConverter instead of IValueConverter and then use a MultiBinding to pass both CountryCode and countries (exposed as a property). You would then access and cast values[0] and values[1] to use them to do the lookup in the Convert method.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountryNameLookupConverter}">
            <Binding Path="CountryCode" />
            <Binding Path="Countries" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

If you are exposing countries statically (i.e. Lookup.Countries), you can pass the collection to your IValueConverter either as a property or through the ConverterParameter. Here's the converter with a property:

```
public class CountryNameLookupConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> LookupList { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Country country = LookupList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code.Equals(value));
        if (country == null)
            return "Not Found";
        return country.Name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

and the converter resource would be declared like:

```
<local:CountryNameLookupConverter x:Key="CountryNameLookupConverter" LookupList="{x:Static local:Lookup.Countries}"/>
```

Or to pass into Convert's object parameter instead:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryCode, Converter={StaticResource CountryNameLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Lookup.Countries}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the last of your options with some lazy loading lists. Works really well.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make your countries object public static and put it in the Country class. eg:

```
public class Country
{
    public static List<Country> Countries;
    public string Code { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

You could read from your XML file and set this in the constructor for your application or something like that (or wherever it might be necessary). eg:

```
Country.Countries = <deserialized objects from file>;
```

that way you can get the list at any time from anywhere in your application.

Edit:
You could also use ConverterParameter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryCode, Converter={StaticResource CountryNameLookupConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding Path=Countries}}"/>
```

Comment: ConverterParameter={Binding Path=Countries} is wrong, Binding cannot be set on the ConverterParameter. Binding target has to be a DependencyProperty

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you may need an ORM to create your models as they seem to contain a relationship between them. Else check this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170907234900/http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/06/03/demystifying-dlinq-part2--setting-up-a-datacontext-class.aspx) to create the EntitySets and EntityRefs manually which helps in lookups. You may also be interested in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/digital_ruminations/linq-to-sql-poco-support).

Whatever it is, ultimately you need to have a list of Address in the Customer Class.

By the way, where does the Address Model come from?